# How do I run this Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to run this Makefil but I don't know really how to do it.
Here's the code:

```
CXX = clang++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra

all: hopscotch_hashing clean

hopscotch_hashing: hopscotch_hashing.o hash_funcs.o hopscotch_main.o
    ${CXX} ${CFLAGS} -o hopscotch_hashing hopscotch_main.o \
        hopscotch_hashing.o hash_funcs.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.dSYM
    rm *.o

hopscotch_main.o: hopscotch_main.cpp
hopscotch_hashing.o: hopscotch_hashing.h hopscotch_hashing.cpp
hash_funcs.o: hash_funcs.h hash_funcs.cpp
```

It's the first time that I encounter this, I'm working on Windows 10.
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Makefiles are not scripts.  You can't run them.  Rather, they are the control input to the `make` program, so it is `make` that you run.  But Windows does not have a native `make` (it has a similar utility that I think comes with Visual Studio, but this is not compatible).  Nor does it have a POSIX shell, upon which that makefile relies, or the Clang compiler suite.  Overall, then, the short answer is "you don't".  The long answer is "It's complicated, involving a Unix compatibility environment and toolchain, or maybe WSL".

Comment: That does not even consider the question of whether the program itself is Windows-compatible.  That it is written in C++ in no way guarantees that.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google for *GNU make*. Find the instructions to install on your system. Then run `gmake` from the directory containing your `Makefile`. Or it might just be `make` -- see the instructions when you install *GNU make* for specifics.

Comment: GNU Make is a program name, not code. Only code should be formatted in backticks. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) on [meta].

Answer (score 0):

As the OP question is "How do I run this Makefile?", a proper answer would be: You need an interpreter for makefiles in windows environment, such as nmake and gnu make.
Nmake is shipped in Windows SDK.
Gnu Make: you need a gnu development for windows like msys2.
Notice that both nmake and gnu make have different syntax if you are planning to work with makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

One option to compile your code is to use CygWin (https://cygwin.com/)

It contains GNU Make, the clang compiler, a shell, and thousands of Unix/Linux tools ported to Windows. From their FAQ:

> Cygwin is a distribution of popular GNU and other Open Source tools
> running on Microsoft Windows. The core part is the Cygwin library
> which provides the POSIX system calls and environment these programs
> expect.
>
> The Cygwin distribution contains thousands of packages from the Open
> Source world including most GNU tools, many BSD tools, an X server and
> a full set of X applications. If you're a developer you will find
> tools, headers and libraries allowing to write Windows console or GUI
> applications that make use of significant parts of the POSIX API.
> Cygwin allows easy porting of many Unix programs without the need for
> extensive changes to the source code. This includes configuring and
> building most of the available GNU or BSD software, including the
> packages included with the Cygwin distribution themselves. They can be
> used from one of the provided Unix shells like bash, tcsh or zsh

The installer is quite friendly, allows you to select which extra packages you need (in your case make and clang++). You can also install other compilers (like GNU g++), the GNU or the LLVM debuggers, and a long etcetera.